# Matlab: get top/bottom 2 ranked observations by each group in a table

Tags: matlab

I would like to get top and bottom 2 ranked observations by each group in a table in matlab. I do not have groupfilter function available.

I have a table like this:

```
MeasurementTime = datetime({'2015-12-18 08:03:05';'2015-12-18 10:03:17';'2015-12-18 12:03:13'});
VAR1 = [37.3;39.1;42.3];
VAR2 = [30.1;30.03;29.9];
VAR3 = [13.4;6.5;7.3];
VAR4 = [3.4;1.5;0.3];
VAR5 = [3.9;1.1;0.2];
TT = timetable(MeasurementTime,VAR1, VAR2, VAR3, VAR4, VAR5)
TT1 = stack(TT, {'VAR1','VAR2','VAR3','VAR4','VAR5'},'NewDataVariableName','Value','IndexVariableName','Group')
```

```
  MeasurementTime       Group    Value
____________________    _____    _____

18-Dec-2015 08:03:05    VAR1      37.3
18-Dec-2015 08:03:05    VAR2      30.1
18-Dec-2015 08:03:05    VAR3      13.4
18-Dec-2015 08:03:05    VAR4       3.4
18-Dec-2015 08:03:05    VAR5       3.9
18-Dec-2015 10:03:17    VAR1      39.1
18-Dec-2015 10:03:17    VAR2     30.03
18-Dec-2015 10:03:17    VAR3       6.5
18-Dec-2015 10:03:17    VAR4       1.5
18-Dec-2015 10:03:17    VAR5       1.1
18-Dec-2015 12:03:13    VAR1      42.3
18-Dec-2015 12:03:13    VAR2      29.9
18-Dec-2015 12:03:13    VAR3       7.3
18-Dec-2015 12:03:13    VAR4       0.3
18-Dec-2015 12:03:13    VAR5       0.2
```

The group is the MeasurementTime. Ideally I would like to have this for top 2 observations:

```
  MeasurementTime       Group    Value
____________________    _____    _____

18-Dec-2015 08:03:05    VAR1      37.3
18-Dec-2015 08:03:05    VAR2      30.1
18-Dec-2015 10:03:17    VAR1      39.1
18-Dec-2015 10:03:17    VAR2     30.03
18-Dec-2015 12:03:13    VAR1      42.3
18-Dec-2015 12:03:13    VAR2      29.9
```

for bottom 2 observations:

```
  MeasurementTime       Group    Value
____________________    _____    _____

18-Dec-2015 08:03:05    VAR4       3.4
18-Dec-2015 08:03:05    VAR5       3.9
18-Dec-2015 10:03:17    VAR4       1.5
18-Dec-2015 10:03:17    VAR5       1.1
18-Dec-2015 12:03:13    VAR4       0.3
18-Dec-2015 12:03:13    VAR5       0.2
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure what you mean by "top 2 observations" and "bottom 2 observations", and unfortunately I can't comment, so I'll just try to replicate your desired output as:

```
TTtop2 = stack(TT(:,1:2),{'VAR1','VAR2'},'NewDataVariableName','Value','IndexVariableName','Group')

TTbottom2 = stack(TT(:,4:5),{'VAR4','VAR5'},'NewDataVariableName','Value','IndexVariableName','Group')
```